# Основания для отрицательных оценок

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, репутация, голоса-против

Сейчас любой вопрос или ответ можно "минусануть" без каких либо обоснований или комментариев, что позволяет кроме объективных причин для своего решения руководствоваться также и хулиганскими побуждениями. Вообще было бы неплохо, чтобы под отрицательным отзывом нужно было бы оставлять свой комментарий, и например анонимно показывать их. Такой подход  позволил бы отсечь необъективные оценки, а в случае объективных замечаний позволил бы отвечающим учитывать их, и тем самым позволять сообществу становиться лучше. Кто как считает по этому поводу?